# Angular Unit Test | service | $httpbackend always execute error branch when responded with 401 or 500 status code

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-mock

I'm using the `$httpbackend`.

When we mock the particular service, we then respond it with status code like 200-209 which triggers success branch and other triggers error branch.

My service can send a response with different status code, and I have to redirect the user to error pages.

If I respond with `401`, or `500` status code, error branch is getting executed. how can I get these status code in success branch.

http://plnkr.co/edit/bDVf9hGdqUZgYTNsm3X9?p=preview

Comment: This is the expected behaviour as 401 and 500 are error codes in HTTP.
You can do the redirecting logic in the error handler itself.

Comment: @MahendraSingh: your comment should be THE answer.

Comment: I'll post a more formal answer.Thanks though for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

As per $http source, the isSuccess method is used to determine if the success callback will be called or not.
Here is the definition of the isSuccess method from the source [$http src](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L400)

```
function isSuccess(status) {
  return 200 <= status && status < 300;
}
```

All the other codes will result in error callback to be called.

So your error page redirection should be done in the error callbacks.

Hope it helps.